# My Broadcast Receiver does not start

Tags: android

I have some problem with BroadcastReceiver. There nothing happens when I catch an outgoing call.

```
public class demoBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context, "there is new calling", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is content of my Manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <receiver  android:name=".demoBroadcastReceiver">
                <intent-filter  >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                </intent-filter> 
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                </intent-filter> 
            </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Updated:**
Thanks *Lucifer* for solution:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
```

I also need this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />**strong text**
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare this permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: you can download a working example from here, http://110.172.27.47:9499/Kalpen/Android/AutoStartExample.zip

Comment: I have created it for Autostart of Activity, you can modify the code and use it

Comment: you welcome. Happy to help you, you can join me live in my chat room  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/

Answer (score 3):

maybe you should post your log here, so we can analyse it.

try add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

Hope this

Answer (score 1):

put this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and this in your application node..

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.demoBroadcastReceiver">  
<intent-filter>  
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  <--- add this intent filter
</intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

this is to start a service when a device boots up on android